# KeyError when trying to print rows from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to extract some rows from a csv file, but can't get the required rows.

this is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv("V:\Coding\coding\clean.csv", sep="\t")
data.columns
title=[]
author=[]
isbn=[]
title.append(data['Titel'])
author.append(data['Autor'])
isbn.append(data['ISBN'])
print(title)
print(author)
print(isbn)
```

This is a part of the csv I'm trying to "clean up": https://pastebin.com/hUfUYwf0

I've managed to print the "author" (as standalone, the title and isbn were commented) , but when I try to print the "title" and "isbn" as well, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\aky547\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> KeyError: 'Autor'

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "v:\Coding\coding\Python\get data from csv.py", line 10, in 
> author.append(data['Autor'])
> File "C:\Users\aky547\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
> File "C:\Users\aky547\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err
> KeyError: 'Autor'

What should I do in order to get all required lines to, in this case print (though later on I want to save them to a new csv)?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is no column named `Autor` in your given .csv file

Comment: @Niqua is right

Comment: my bad, completely missed that...
corrected and is now working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
as in the comment above, there is no column named `Autor`

Probably you need to take the column `Verfasser` if you need authors.

```
author.append(data['Verfasser'])
```